# How do I set the path where gen_py is created (win32com.__gen_path__)

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I'm trying to run a Python subprocess in Python. Specifically it's `WinPython 3.6.1.0`. I am on a company PC so Python is not installed in `C:\Program Files` but in a custom folder.

This is how I start it:

```
envs = {'SYSTEMROOT': r'C:\Windows', 'PATH': config.path_python}
subprocess.run('pip.exe install -e . --no-deps', shell=True, env=envs)
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\gen_py\\3.6\\__init__.py'
```

My guess: It's trying to write `gen_py` to `r'C:\Windows'` where it does not have write privileges, and subsequently fails to read it. I want to fix it by deleting SYSTEMROOT but then I get

```
Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
```

From Google: [1](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1143) [2](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1140). I tried setting `%APPDATA%` to a writable folder (`'APPDATA': r'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming'`) but no dice :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add a `TEMP` key to my `envs` dict. It now looks like so:

```
envs = {
    'SYSTEMROOT': r'C:\Windows', 
    'TEMP': r'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp',
    'PATH': config.path_python
}
```

Comment: Another option is inheriting the env variables (just don't specify `env=`)